# Does mount /system in stock recovery work to root the Android system?

Tags: root-access, recovery-mode

I have an Alcatel Pixi 4 (5) 5040 on Android 6.0. I rebooted into the stock recovery for the first time, and to my surprise I found a Mount /system option available. Now my question is: Can this option be used to push the SU file into the /system partition to gain root access for my Android? If not, then what is the Mount /system option used for?

Comment: As far as I know just pushing an `su` did only work in the early times of Android. Now with SELinux and other protection mechanism it is way more complicated.

Comment: So, the first question is no. What about the second?

Comment: There are devices with two system partitions (since Android N) for installing system updates in background. I assume on devices with two system partitions you have two options to mount different /system partitions.